# reuse kendo grid but change action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to reuse a Kendo  Grid on MVC by calling it on another view as a partial view. The Read property of the Ajax attribute of the grid is set to some method as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
.Ajax()
.Read( read => read.Action("MyMethod", "MyController").Data("getData")))
```

However, I want that when this grid is called from another view, it changes the 'MyMethod' to 'SomeOtherMethod' and 'MyController' to 'SomeOtherController'. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround for what you are trying to achieve. Please see below:

1. In all the views that you are trying to use the grid, set below TempData value:

   ```
   @{TempData["ViewPath"] = @Html.ViewVirtualPath()}
   ```
2. Next you need create a generic master read controller action that will call another controller on the basis of the above tempdata value. So in your case in one view it will call 'MyMethod' of 'MyController' and in some other view it will call 'SomeOtherMethod' of 'SomeOtherController'.

Comment: Thanks, This worked although with some limitations, I couldnt implement @Html.ViewVirtualPath() so I just sent any parameter into the TempData.